# gel band contrast

Tags: proteins, sds-page

Is there any way to increase the contrast of my SDS PAGE gel. I want to increase the coomassie stained gel contrast of my gel bands a little bit as it looks little less for my thesis. Ive heard that it is legal and can be done. Is there any software for it or some other way.[image: this is my gel image below]

Comment: The bands should be a bit clearer (blue background drag in the lanes). You can try improving the protein extraction protocol. Could also be a problem with the gel. Is the leftmost lane your protein ladder?

Comment: If you are asking how to alter the image to make it clearer then your question is off-topic.

Comment: I have made a standardised protocol for protein extraction... this is the best I could get for bands as protein content is less from my sample..I dont want to alter the image just increase the overall contrast....and yes the leftmost lane is my ladder...do you have any suggestion to improve this particular image?

Answer (score 1):

If this is accepted or not depends on your institution. For publications, it is usually accepted to use adjustions of color, tonal values and contrast which are applied to the whole image and which do not alter the statement of the image. These changes are not ok if for example the contrast it raised so much that weak bands disappear.

Not accepted are changes which are only made to changes to parts of the image, partial adding or removal of parts of the image. Keeping this in mind, you can basically use any software which can be used to process images. Photoshop is kind of a standard but pretty expensive, free software like Gimp also does the job.

I adjusted the tonal values of your image and raised the contrast just a little to get this:

[image]

Comment: You got there first. I also took it into PhotoShop and did an "Image>Auto Contrast" (not quite as good) but then went into "Adjustment>Levels" and with the dropper selected an area between the lanes as the white point, which gave a slightly better result.

Comment: this looks much better than my posted image..and yes it is legal over here to adjust the gel as long as we do not tamper the bands...and thanks a lot...do you think this one is good to proceed with or should I tune it a little bit more.

Comment: @Kushal That depends on your desires for the image. For me, this looks fine.

Comment: @Chris okay I'll see to it. and thanks a lot for the help and suggestions.